# SSL certificate not working

Tags: linux, ssl, apache2, openssl, httpd

I'm going to put an application on a new server (after upgrading it from PHP 7 to PHP 8). I can connect to the server(Red Hat) only using VPN (pulse).

my purpose is to run the application on the browser.

when I connect to the server then I run `curl localhost` I get the error `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain` when I run `curl -k localhost` I can see the content of the web page on the terminal.

I tried to access to the application through a web browser and the ip adress of the server but I get `this site can't be reached`

ssl virtual host context:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

How can I access to the application using a web browser ?

Comment: can you reach a page without ssl? if you need a vpn to access it, it's probably a firewall

Comment: Have you set up your certificate properly? What is its configuration? Where did you obtain the certificate? Certificate issuers don't provide certificates for `localhost`, so you cannot test with that. You need to point your DNS to the new server to test.

Comment: I cannot reach my application without ssl

Comment: You are contradicting yourself! If your server is accessible "only using VPN" then you won't reach it with `curl localhost`! First check if you're really get the correct certificate from localhost or your "ip address" or whereever your server is running: `openssl s_client -connect server-ip-address:443 </dev/null|openssl x509 -text -noout`

Comment: "I cannot reach my application without ssl " => even no ssh? And how did you access and install the server? Please add the IP address (or a substitution of it) to the question. Then we can provide some commands for testing. And please remove the VirtualHost config. It's trivial and does not provide important details.

Comment: If you are able to login to the server via `ssh` then you can create a tunnel (as root) via: `ssh -L 443:127.0.0.1:443 youraccount@your-server-ip-address` Then you can access your server via `https://localhost` with any local web browser.

Comment: localhost means you can access the page over the server itself. You can not access page outside. You need to run httpd on IP address to access outside server.